# Reverse geocoding appending twice - possible threading issue

Tags: ios, multithreading, cocoa-touch

So I'm doing this -

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    if (newLocation != nil) {
        currentLocation = newLocation;
    }
    currentLocationString = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@""];

    geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];

    [geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:currentLocation completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
        if (error == nil && [placemarks count] > 0) {
            CLPlacemark* currentLocPlacemark = [placemarks lastObject];
            NSLog(@"FORMATTED ADDR DICT : %@", currentLocPlacemark.addressDictionary);
            [currentLocationString appendString: currentLocPlacemark.addressDictionary[@"Street"]];
            [currentLocationString appendString: @" "];

            [currentLocationString appendString: currentLocPlacemark.addressDictionary[@"City"]];
            NSLog(@"%@", currentLocationString);

            [currentLocationString appendString: @" "];

            [currentLocationString appendString: currentLocPlacemark.addressDictionary[@"Country"]];
            NSLog(@"CURRENTLOCATION STRING : %@", currentLocationString);
        } else {
            NSLog(@"%@", error.debugDescription);
        }
    } ];
    [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
}
```

Sometimes the currentLocationString has two copies of the same string appended, and sometimes it does not. This seems like a threading issue - what's going on? Is there a synchronized keyword in objective C, or some way of getting around this through cocoa-touch?

Comment: Why don't you create the string inside the completion block instead of before the block and then set it at the end of the completion block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens when `reverseGeocodeLocation` has not finished its execution and you receive new location update. So, in the `completionHandler`, you will append the string in the same variable.

To avoid it, you should create the copy of `currentLocationString` inside the `completionHandler`.